# Formal writing in math: equations

Tags: logic, soft-question, article-writing, formal-grammar

What is the formally correct way to solve a bunch of equations in math?

Is it \begin{align} 42x = 4324 \\ x = 4324/42 \end{align} or \begin{align} 42x = 4324 \\ \Rightarrow x = 4324/42 \end{align} or \begin{align} 42x = 4324 \\ \Leftrightarrow x = 4324/42 \end{align}
or \begin{align} 42x = 4324 \\ \text{and so} \ x = 4324/42 \end{align}
or something completely different? I've been using the second listed above (it looks the best), and now my instructor just told me that it's wrong to use that logical symbol in that manner.

Comment: The third alternative is the best, I think. I would prefer that.

Comment: Your instructor would have to be more specific. "Formal" is a loose term, in this case. Even more formally we would say. $$42x=4324\\42x=4324\implies x=4324/42\\x=4324/42\text{ (modus ponens)}$$ or something of the like. Absolute formal mathematics, on the other hand, would be even drearier. Your notation is conflating these two logical steps, but I wouldn't call it wrong, it's a fairly common shorthand.

Comment: Really any of those are fine, which one to use in any particular instance would have to depend on the context.  You could also replace "and so" with "thus," "therefore," "it follows that," "which implies," "giving".  You may mix it up not to use the same one several times in a row, it should read smoothly, like any good English exposition.

Comment: I disagree with your teacher, I think it's fine to use $\Rightarrow$ in that way.

Comment: You better take a step towards Logic now. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem your instructor has (I think) is that you state a set of propositions with these symbols, and a proposition is either false or true. In the case of a set of propositions it can be true for some $x$ and for some $x$ it can be false. For example, it is perfectly fine to state $$[42x=4324] \Rightarrow [x=35867879]$$

Which is true for all $x \neq \frac{4324}{42}$.

The same goes actually for the third. This leaves the first and the fourth. Since the first is less writing, I would prefer the first.

Comment: A proposition is a declarative sentence which is either true or false but never both. In particlar, $42x=4324$ is not a proposition because we haven't assigned  a value to $x$ yet.

Comment: @SufyanNaeem Do explain it better this way?

Comment: I would just use the word "statement" rather than proposition. What you have written is still not a proposition, although you could make it one by adding $\forall x$ or $\exists x$. Still, this distinction is usually not made in casual language.

Answer (score 1):

There are two very different ideas among your proposals:

1. Implication: $\implies$ or "and so" indicate that the second row follows from the first by some logical inference rule.
2. Equivalence: $\iff$ indicates a double implication, the first row reciprocally follows from the first. This is a stronger statement.

In your example it makes no difference, but it would in an asymmetrical case like $x=3$ vs. $x^2=9$.

When solving an equation, a straight implication $\implies$ ensures that you don't drop a solution, while reverse implication $\impliedby$ ensures that no solution extra solution is introduced. For a correct solution, you need equivalence.

So the notation $\iff$ is bulletproof, while with other variants you should make your meaning explicit.

Answer (score 0):

To use $\implies$ is problematic as it does not really do what you want.

When you have (Eq 1) $\implies$  (Eq 2) and $x$ is a solution of (Eq 2) then it does not follow that $x$ is a solution of (Eq 1).

You only get that if $x$ is a solution of (Eq 1) then it is also a solution of (Eq 2). Thus (Eq 2) gives your restrictions on the solutions of (Eq 1). You then would have to go back and check if the soltutions of (Eq 2) actually are solutions of (Eq 1).

If you do not do this, you did not really solve (Eq 1). To avoid this you should write an equivalence $\Leftrightarrow$.